# Data table creation issue

Tags: jquery

I have an HTML table:

```
    <table id="TabId" style="width: 100%; border: 0; cellspacing: 0; cellpadding: 0;" class="margin-8">
            <tr>
            <th style="width: 5%;">Select</th>
            <th style="width: 5%;">ID</th>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach var="vp" items="${vpList}" varStatus="rowCounter">
              <tr>
                .... tds here ....
              </tr>
            </c:forEach>
   </table>
```

and I have the code :

```
$("#TabId").dataTable
     ({
         "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
         "bProcessing" : true,
         "bJQueryUI" : true,
         "bRetrieve" :true
     });
```

I included the following files:

```
<script src="/tool/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="/tool/css/demo_table_jui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/tool/css/demo_table.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

But still, the data table is not coming. Am I missing something?

Comment: If any error message in console, let us know...

Comment: TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function

Comment: But are you including jquery???

Comment: Have u included datatable.js file... Because you have function error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add jquery plugin to your page

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You might be missing the script reference to jquery library itself. The plugin script reference should be underneath the jQ library reference.